# Position Image in line with text?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get an image to sit directly next, to the left of a navigation bar item on bootstrap, I have almost got it, infact it works perfectly with small images, but as soon as I create a bigger image it messes up.

I have tried making the right of the image really small like 20px, but it makes no difference.

I haven't tried changing the width because I need the width to stay the same. I am not changing the height with size but with clipping, see the css below for more information on how I am doing it.

Unfortinately I can't place the image because stackoverflow says the format is not allowed, but here is the preview of how it looks: 

http://image.prntscr.com/image/2445963b2dda43399a32c152675ceaa3.png

CSS:

```
#clip {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0, 100px, 70px, 0);
    /* clip: shape(top, right, bottom, left); NB 'rect' is the only available option */
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle profile-image" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        <img id="clip" src="https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=img&figure=hr-828-52.hd-180-1.lg-280-1422.ch-3032-66-1408&action=wav&direction=2&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=m" />
 &nbsp;&nbsp;Adam Sandler <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account</a></li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign-out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
```

I also use bootstraps css, but I wont paste all that here.

I have put all the code together on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ovjfeukc

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the below is what you desire, but you can change the `position: absolute;` to `display: inline-block;`

```css
#clip {
  display: inline-block;
  clip: rect(0, 100px, 70px, 0);
  /* clip: shape(top, right, bottom, left); NB 'rect' is the only available option */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle profile-image" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <img id="clip" src="https://www.habbo.com.br/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?hb=img&figure=hr-828-52.hd-180-1.lg-280-1422.ch-3032-66-1408&action=wav&direction=2&head_direction=3&gesture=sml&size=m" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;Adam Sandler <b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Account</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Sign-out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You also have padding from the .profile-image link tag that's causing the placement issue. You don't need absolute positioning on the image either. I just shrunk it with the height attribute, but you can fiddle around with that. Try these classes:

```
.profile-image {padding-top:0 !important; padding-bottom:0 !important;}

#clip {height:50px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7845apm9/